# How to load all images in folder by its name using python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a folder with 50000 images named as `ILSVRC2012_val_00000001.JPEG` until `ILSVRC2012_val_00050000.JPEG`.
I want to load each image and then used them to something. Here, that's the code I'm using (load just first 14 images):

```
for m in range(0,15):

    count = m + 1

    im = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_PATH_FOLDER + 'ILSVRC2012_val_000' + str(count).zfill(5) + '.JPEG')
```

The **error** is

```
No such file or directory: ILSVRC2012_val_00000010.JPEG
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have a look at [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). Check if its output shows the files. Also, check the output of [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

Comment: I'd use `glob.glob` personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `glob.glob`.

```
from glob import glob

for path in sorted(glob(IMAGE_PATH_FOLDER + "ILSVRC2012_val_*.JPEG")):
    im = caffe.io.load_image(path)
```

Comment: Using this, when I print path I get

/home/filipa/Documents/Validation_Set/ILSVRC2012_val_00030560.JPEG

I want it to start by image ILSVRC2012_val_00000001.JPEG

Comment: @FilipaAlmeida Fixed, you can apply sorted to the result of `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use absolute path like this.

the following example relevant to linux, but you can apply on windows as well.

```
/home/<your_directory>/ILSVRC2012_val_00000010.JPEG
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to ask python to list all the files in the directory, then work on them

```
import os
import caffe

directory = r"/Users/Photos/Foo"
file_names = os.listdir(directory)
for file_name in file_names:
    if file_name [:14] == "ILSVRC2012_val_":
        full_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
        im = caffe.io.load_image(full_path)
```